# use of : in android (manifest.xml)

Tags: android-studio-3.0

```
<application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

what is the use of : in android , I ask this cause it is really hard to search similar questions about symbol online , thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Android specific. It is XML specific, which is called "XML namespace".

You can find a definition of `android:` at the root element of this XML file.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```